# Running applescript while screen saver is activated

Tags: applescript

I wanted to play a iTunes folder playlist at certain time, I figured out this part myself.
But the thing is, I wanted to switch iTunes to mini player afterwards. So here's the code

```
tell application "iTunes" to quit
delay 5

tell application "iTunes"
    reopen
    activate
    set song repeat to all
    set shuffle enabled to true
    set sound volume to 35
    delay 5
    get name of AirPlay devices
    set selected of AirPlay device "Airport Express" to true
    play playlist "mom's music"
end tell

delay 20

-- here comes the part I don't get

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        set frontmost to true
        if title of window 1 is "미니 플레이어" then
            click menu item 9 of menu 9 of menu bar 1
            delay 5
            click menu item 9 of menu 9 of menu bar 1
        else
            click menu item 9 of menu 9 of menu bar 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

never mind the upper parts. Please take a look the part with "System Events".

It does work just as expected when screen saver is NOT running, but it doesn't when screen saver is running, but I can't figure out what I missed.

So, is there another limitation running applescript under screen saver I'm not aware of? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

2017-09-17 add

I came to notice when I press "Window" menu item, `iTunes` (the main one) window disappears. Would that mean I have to be beyond screen saver to do anything with windows through applescript?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when the screen saver is running, the script will still run but not process certain events. The workaround is to stop the screen saver before running any code that depends on UI Scripting, in this case.

Example:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 53 -- # Esc key.
    delay 1 - # Adjust as necessary, the screen saver needs to have stopped before continuing.
    tell process "iTunes"
        set frontmost to true
        if title of window 1 is "미니 플레이어" then
            click menu item 9 of menu 9 of menu bar 1
            delay 5
            click menu item 9 of menu 9 of menu bar 1
        else
            click menu item 9 of menu 9 of menu bar 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It didn't work both on my mac mini and macbook air tho. Can it be because of ESC key wasn't enough to stop the screen saver? Again thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this version

```
try
    tell application id "com.apple.ScreenSaver.Engine" to quit
end try

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        set frontmost to true
        if title of window 1 is "미니 플레이어" then
            click menu item 9 of menu 9 of menu bar 1
            delay 5
            click menu item 9 of menu 9 of menu bar 1
        else
            click menu item 9 of menu 9 of menu bar 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```